# Overlapping axes in GUI when plotting boxplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, boxplot, axes

I am creating a GUI in MATLAB using GUIDE. I have several axes, and in one of them I want to draw a boxplot. My problem is that after drawing the boxplot, the size of the axes changes, and it overlaps with some of my other figures.

To replicate this problem, create a `.fig` file using `GUIDE` containing two axes: `axes1` and `axes2`, as shown in the figure: [image: Example of .fig with two axes].

Then, in the `OpeningFcn`, add the following lines:

```
Z = normrnd(1,3,[100,1]);
plot(handles.axes1, Z);
boxplot(handles.axes2,Z)
```

Then lauch the GUI. I see the following:

[image: GUI when launching the program]

As you can see, the two axes overlap. I've tried changing the properties of the box plot, but with no luck.

I use MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a) and Kubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that `boxplot` makes the axes grow wider, not sure why. In any case, saving the axes position right before plotting and resetting it right after seems to work for me:

```
Z = normrnd(1,3,[100,1]);
plot(handles.axes1, Z);
pos = get(handles.axes2, 'position');
boxplot(handles.axes2,Z);
set(handles.axes2, 'position', pos);
```

Cheers,
Giuseppe

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't explain why boxplot changes my axes position, but it works, so I guess that's enough :)

Comment: boxplot is a complex, high-level command (over 4000 lines of code!). As much as I usually dislike this type of workaround, in this case I would just try and see if other problems pop up down the line. Cheers